# node-mongodb-native - cursor returns null as last value during an each call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

So. I have a very basic script, that connects to a database and does a `find` on a collection that has a lot of documents and limit it to 3 items. Everything runs smoothly except that at the end of my results, a `null` and the script doesn't terminate instead of closing the connection quietly after having succeedeed.

Here I declare my params and create my database object:

```
var SERVER = 'localhost',
 PORT = 27017,
 DATABASE = 'test',
 COLLECTION = 'coll',
 mongo = require('mongodb'),
 db = new mongo.Db(DATABASE,
  new mongo.Server(SERVER, PORT, {auto_reconnect: true}),
  {});
```

And here I connect to the database and proceed to query it with a `find` cursor and the `each` function:

```
db.open(function(err, db) {
 if(err) throw err;
 var collection = new mongo.Collection(db, COLLECTION),
  cursor = collection.find({}, {}).limit(3);
 cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(doc);
 });
 db.close();
});
```

Results are nice:

```
{ _id: '1',
  a: 'first object' }
{ _id: '2',
  a: 'second object' }
{ _id: '3',
  a: 'third object' }
```

up until the point where a

```
null
```

appears.

As described above, the script then proceeds not to terminate.

I don't get why and would appreciate pointers on how to make it terminate nicely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that was stupid. Too much time without programming in an async setup and you make mistakes: the `db.close()` call came before the `each` looping was over. Returned `null` and hanged because of that. Here is the correct code:

```
db.open(function(err, db) {
 if(err) throw err;
 var collection = new mongo.Collection(db, COLLECTION),
  cursor = collection.find({}, {}).limit(3);
 cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
  if(err) throw err;
  if(doc !== null) console.log(doc);
  else db.close();
 });
});
```

I hope it'll save some minutes to someone, somehow.

Answer (score 10):

This question's a few years old, and already has a possible answer, but I just wanted to point out another possibility for anyone who's still confused after reading this. Turns out, `each` repeatedly calls `nextObject` which actually is intended to return null when the cursor is exhausted.

The answer here was the one I needed: [Node Mongo Native - how to tell when a cursor is exhausted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826520/node-mongo-native-how-to-tell-when-a-cursor-is-exhausted)

From the Node MongoDB driver docs: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#nextobject

Comment: This should be the actual answer.

Comment: Even, I was getting a null as the last value during call to cursor.each. nodejs version : 0.12.9 , mongodb ddriver version : ^2.2.33. Good that I saw this answer.